# Switch between two UIViewControllers programmatically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two xib files and for each it's own class which overrides UIViewController class. I have a button in first xib file which should take me to new UIViewController when it's pressed. I have managed to make that transition in different ways:

```
UIViewController* secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewControllerName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

or

```
UIViewController* secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewControllerName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

In second UIViewController xib file I have also one button which should take me back to first UIViewController. But I don't know how to navigate back to first UIViewController.

I tried:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

for second way of navigating to second UIViewController, but I get *unrecognized selector sent to instance* error.

Many thanks in advance for any kind of help.

---

**[edit #1: Adding source code]**

Here's source code of first view controller .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)switchToSecondPage:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];

    [UIView commitAnimations];  

}

@end
```

Here's source code of second view controller .m file:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)switchToFirstPage:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

Here's my AppDelegate.m file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

@end
```

Entire project is made as Single View Application and targeted for iOS 5.1 in XCode 4.3. I have found sample project which does the same thing I am having trouble with. Here's URL for that project: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42476/0/page/2
It is just written for earlier iOS version. Is anyone able to see what am I doing wrong, since I am really out of ideas?

PS: With this animations in code, or without - same problem occurs, so animations aren't problem, I've checked that.

---

**[edit #2: Adding error info]**

Here's error description. In main method on return line as listed below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc00000008)

---

**[edit #3: SOLUTION]**

I would like to thank @btype for his solution below. I found out why code from edit #2 didn't work. Problem was doing this:

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

**INSIDE OF IBAction METHOD!** Looks like ARC wiped my UIViewController as soon as end of scope was reached and that's why I was getting informations about sending messages to released instance. I made SecondViewController private field in my ViewController class and after that everything worked just fine.

If anyone thinks my explanation is wrong and knows what really bothered me, feel free to answer to this question and correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the code:

in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

FirstViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)switchToSecondPage:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

SeconViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)switchToFirstPage:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This should help.

Comment: I just wrote this to @jackiedigital. IBAction isn't called, but viewDidLoad from my second UIViewController isn't called either. And I am pretty sure that I attached IBAction properly to my only UIButton I have in this xib file.

Comment: Check if your Files Owner has the same Class? Is the view outlet connected to your view? Is your button connected to the files owner? do you connect the 'touch up inside' event of your button to the files owners IBAction method? Just trying to provide some hints...

Comment: I have FirstViewController and SecondViewController (.m and .h) files. FirstViewController is set as File Owner for first xib file, SecondViewController is set for second xib file. I have IBOutlet for button on first xib file, and also one IBOutlet for button on second. They are connected well with buttons on xib file, but I am not using that connection for anything at this moment. I made IBAction for button on first xib file which makes transition to second one and that method is being called and transition is made to second UIViewController. Same thing I did in SecondViewController class.

Comment: And I have connected that IBAction to my only button on 'Touch Up Inside' event. I don't know did I miss to check anything nor what I did wrong.

Comment: If your IBAction is connected correctly, your method should be called. Did you check the naming of your IBAction? Is it the same in header and main file? Try to set visual hints (e.g. make a red background for the button to identify if its the right view).

Comment: Definitely triple checked everything. Everything's in perfect order. Do you even have a clue why viewDidLoad method isn't called when second UIViewController shows up?

Comment: viewDidLoad is called before the view is presented. I have no clue why it's not happening in your case. Next step is to create a new viewController to use instead ;)

Comment: I have edited my question and added source code of my now really DUMMY project with only 2 xib files and 2 view controllers. Are you seeing maybe something in that code I don't? I am really out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works! I figured out later that with navigation the problem was that I didn't have UINavigationController initialized. This solution shows navigation bar on the top, so it must be hidden, but main thing - this works. Many thanks @btype, I will mark your code above as solution to my question, although I found out why my code from question didn't work. I will edit my question and explain my observations. Many thanks for your patience and answer once more! Cheers!